# Using AutoMapper how can a source value be validated before being mapped?

Tags: c#, datetime, automapper

I have an AutoMapper mapping defined from DateTime to string, in which I use ISO-8601 date format and truncate the time part.

I would like to strictly enforce DateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc on the source value, such that if the source date is not DateTimeKind.Utc I would like the mapping to fail, i.e. by throwing an exception.

Is this the right way of going about this? If so, what is the proper way of achieving this?

Here is my mapping profile for this:

```
public DateTimeMappingProfile()
{
    // TODO: Ideally we would throw an exception if DateTime.Kind is not UTC.
    CreateMap<DateTime, string>()
        .ConvertUsing(dt => dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    CreateMap<string, DateTime>()
        .ConvertUsing(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ConvertUsing` overload accepting a mapping function (instead of an expression).

```
void ConvertUsing(Func<TSource, TDestination, TDestination> mappingFunction)
```

That one allows to have an `Exception` thrown.

```
CreateMap<DateTime, string>()
    .ConvertUsing((source, destination) => source.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc
        ? source.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        : throw new Exception("DateTime must be of kind Utc")
        );
```